# My logic for seeing if a user has won a tic-tac-toe match isn't working

Tags: swift

Below is some code to check if somebody has won on a tic tac toe board. (board[0] - board[8] represent the tic tac toe board from top to bottom, left to right):

```
func checkWin(board: [Int]) -> Bool{
    if board[0] != 0 {
        if board[0] == board[1] && board[1] == board[2] {
            return true
        } else if board[0] == board[3] && board[3] == board[6] {
            return true
        }
    } else if board[4] != 0 {
        if board[1] == board[4] && board[4] == board[7] {
            return true
        } else if board[3] == board[4] && board[4] == board[5] {
            return true
        } else if board[2] == board[4] && board[4] == board[6] {
            return true
        } else if board[0] == board[4] && board[4] == board[8] { //
            return true
        }
    } else if board[8] != 0 {
        if board[2] == board[5] && board[5] == board[8] { //
            return true
        } else if board[6] == board[7] && board[7] == board[8] { //
            return true
        }
    }
return false
}
```

However, the three lines with // at the end will not return true even if the conditions are met. I have noticed that they all share board[8], however I know this is not a problem with the storyboard, as if I hard code a win that satisfies one of faulty conditions it still doesn't work. Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Comment: What's the point of the three outer `if` statements? What values can each `board` entry have?

Comment: I'm guessing `0` is empty space, `1` is player 1 and `2` is player 2.  So the outer ifs are there to prevent recognizing 3 empty spaces in a row as a win.

Comment: If you finish a game and print the board array, does it mirror the game end state'?

Comment: This might be of interest to you: [Tic Tac Toe in Swift](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/tic-tac-toe-in-swift)  on Code Review.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is flawed.  Once you check with the outer `if`s, you have committed to just checking a few of the possible cases.

For instance, if space `0` is not empty, then you are only checking cases `0-1-2` and `0-3-6`, but you aren't checking `0-4-8` so you'll miss that possibility.  The `0-4-8` case is handled inside the first `else if` case, but you'll never get there if `board[0] != 0`.

You can fix this by using 3 `if`s instead of the `else if`s.

```
func checkWin(board: [Int]) -> Bool{
    print(board)
    if board[0] != 0 {
        if board[0] == board[1] && board[1] == board[2] {
            return true
        } else if board[0] == board[3] && board[3] == board[6] {
            return true
        }
    }
    if board[4] != 0 {
        if board[1] == board[4] && board[4] == board[7] {
            return true
        } else if board[3] == board[4] && board[4] == board[5] {
            return true
        } else if board[2] == board[4] && board[4] == board[6] {
            return true
        } else if board[0] == board[4] && board[4] == board[8] { //
            return true
        }
    }
    if board[8] != 0 {
        if board[2] == board[5] && board[5] == board[8] { //
            return true
        } else if board[6] == board[7] && board[7] == board[8] { //
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Good catch about the "else if"! – I stared at the code and did not see it :)

Comment: The code looked right to me as well.  Then I tried `checkWin(board: [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1])` and to my surprise it returned `false`.  This makes the case for good unit test cases.

Comment: for me your code returned `true`

Comment: @muescha, I meant that the original code returned `false`.  My fixed code does return `true`.

Comment: @vacawama ok :)

Comment: Sorry for a late reply but thanks! Didn't spot that if one if statement executed then the else ifs wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

a little bit more compact:

```
func checkWin(board: [Int]) -> Bool{

    let checks = [
        //rows
        [0,1,2],
        [3,4,5],
        [6,7,8],
        //columns
        [0,3,6],
        [1,4,7],
        [2,5,8],
        //cross
        [0,4,8],
        [2,4,6]
    ]

    for check in checks{
        if    board[check[0]] != 0
           && board[check[0]] == board[check[1]]
           && board[check[1]] == board[check[2]]
        {    
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

better to get also the winner-id or 0 for no winner:

```
func getWinner(board: [Int]) -> Int{

    let checks = [
        //rows
        [0,1,2],
        [3,4,5],
        [6,7,8],
        //columns
        [0,3,6],
        [1,4,7],
        [2,5,8],
        //cross
        [0,4,8],
        [2,4,6]
    ]

    for check in checks{
        if    board[check[0]] != 0
           && board[check[0]] == board[check[1]]
           && board[check[1]] == board[check[2]]
        {
            return board[check[0]]
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

or if you like to put it in an enum:

```
enum Winner {
    case none
    case player(id: Int)
}

func checkWin(board: [Int]) -> Winner{

    let checks = [
        //rows
        [0,1,2],
        [3,4,5],
        [6,7,8],
        //columns
        [0,3,6],
        [1,4,7],
        [2,5,8],
        //cross
        [0,4,8],
        [2,4,6]
    ]

    for check in checks{
        if   board[check[0]] != 0
          && board[check[0]] == board[check[1]]
          && board[check[1]] == board[check[2]]
        {
            return .player(id: board[check[0]])
        }
    }
    return .none
}
```